# Android: How to get image using MediaMetadataRetriever?

Tags: android

I'm developing a music player on android and i get a bug that i dont know why. I think I do right but it does not work.

I did search a lot of MediaMetadataRetriever, but I still don't see what my problem is.

I use MediaMetadataRetriever to get infomation about my song. Everything work fine but getEmbeddedPicture(). I get this message whenever getEmbeddedPicture called: 
11-15 13:36:11.101: E/MediaMetadataRetrieverJNI(460): getEmbeddedPicture: Call to getEmbeddedPicture failed.

I know this method only called after setDataSource called, and I did it, but I still get that bug ( of course, my song has image in it and I'm using android 2.3.3).

This is the code:

```
mediaInfo.setDataSource(filePath);//filePath is correct.
byte[] img = mediaInfo.getEmbeddedPicture();//cause error
if (img != null)
    imgAlbum.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(img, 0,img.length));
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

The following should work:

```
MediaMetadataRetriever retriever = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
retriever.setDataSource(filePath);
byte[] art = retriever.getEmbeddedPicture();

if( art != null ){
    imgAlbum.setImageBitmap( BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(art, 0, art.length));
}
else{
    imgAlbum.setImageResource(R.drawable.no_image);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try [FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever](https://github.com/wseemann/FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever):

```
FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever retriever = new FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever();
retriever.setDataSource(filePath);
byte[] image = retriever.getEmbeddedPicture();
if (image != null) {
    imgAlbum.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(image, 0,image.length));
}
retriever.release();
```

Comment: hi . i use your library . but seems it so huge! when add this library my apk file from 2mb become to 26mb! is any chance for fix this ?